# Google Tag Manager with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

How do I use GTM with Angular?

I'm trying to fire a (virtual) pageview event when I load a new partial using this code:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event' : 'pageview',
    'pageview' : $location.path(),
    'virtualUrl' : $location.path()
 });
```

But I don't see the event firing (I'm using the Google Analytics Chrome debug extension to view fired events).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I find the Chrome extension unreliable.
Simply run the global variable `dataLayer` in the console to print the array of events. One of the objects should be your pageview event.

Here is an example of how we are using it:

Note: we're not simply using `$location.path()`, instead everything in the url after the domain. Which includes the `.search()` & `.hash()`.

[$location in the Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

#### modules/analytic.js

```
(function(window, angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('Analytic.module', ['Analytic.services']).
        run(function($rootScope, $window, $location, GoogleTagManager) {
            $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
                var path= $location.path(),
                    absUrl = $location.absUrl(),
                    virtualUrl = absUrl.substring(absUrl.indexOf(path));
                GoogleTagManager.push({ event: 'virtualPageView', virtualUrl: virtualUrl });
            });
        });
})(window, window.angular);
```

#### services/analytic.js

```
(function() {
    angular.module('Analytic.services', []).
        service('GoogleTagManager', function($window) {
            this.push = function(data) {
                try {
                    $window.dataLayer.push(data);
                } catch (e) {}
            };
        });
})();
```

#### In GTM

You'll need `{{virtualUrl}}` and `{{event}}` Macros which listen for the dataLayer variables of the same name.

You'll need a Google Analytics Event Tracking Tag with a Firing Rule which triggers when `{{event}}` equals 'virtualPageView'. Make sure you remove the default 'All Pages' Rule which makes it run on every page load. Instead, you want it to run when you `dataLayer.push()` the event, which may happen multiple times per page refresh.

The Tag should be configured with:

1. Track Type == 'Page View'
2. More Settings > Basic Configuration > Virtual Page Path == '{{virtualUrl}}'

Comment: Wow thanks my GTM finally works!  I can even view the live events in GA real-time.  Thanks so much.  It's been killing me for days.

Comment: btw, why do you use everything in the url after the domain, instead of just the path?

Comment: It was a requirement from our analytics guy. Some of the older pages on the site use querystrings instead of paths. "backwards compatibility"...

Comment: I want to use this from bower :)

Comment: This should be marked as the answer if it works for you @ChristianTHC

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the accepted answer, we created a simpler, more explicit solution using a `pagename` variable in a Javascript in our controller for our single-page app,

```
// Note, this may not be how your app works, YMMV
var pagename = $location.path().substr(1,$location.path().length);
```

and push them to the dataLayer like this:

```
window.dataLayer.push({'event':pagename+'-page'})
```

Then in GTM we added triggers in GTM like so:

```
Trigger: Custom Event
Event Name: home-page
```

... about-page, faq-page, etc.

For more complex angular apps, there are some available extensions for using Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager with Angular.

See [Angulartics](http://angulartics.github.io/) (which also supports web analytics solutions other than Google Analytics via its plugin architecture) and the related [NPM package for GTM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angulartics-google-tag-manager).

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you to use the [angulartics](http://angulartics.github.io/) library. I have used it on multiple sites. It gets you running pretty quickly.

It includes support for Virtual Page Views and events out of the box. It does not support GA eCommerce but has support for extensibility.

Also - I have used with both GTM and Piwik.

Answer (score 1):

No need to add code.

Configure a "history change" trigger, this is triggered by angular route changes, add it as a trigger to your "page views" tag.

Answer (score -1):

The possible way to do this is using `$window` service.
Look at this answer to try, if it works: [Tracking Google Analytics Page Views with Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713708/tracking-google-analytics-page-views-with-angular-js#10713709)
Hope it works.

Comment: Yeah I've read through that page, but it uses traditional GA, whereas I need to use the new GTM system.

Comment: I am sorry but i don't have any experience with GTM. Hope you get a solution.