# How to install google analytics javascript on an overlay where content resides?

Tags: user-interface, analytics

Typically, if it were a regular page-by-page website, I would install the analytics javascript before the body tag.

But, with a site where content is on overlays, how can analytics be installed to track views? (i.e. a one page portfolio site)

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript that calls the overlay, you can add:

`_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/url/of/page']);`

or:

`ga('send','pageview','/url/of/page');`

Answer (score 0):

See [Tracking Google Analytics Page Views with Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713708/tracking-google-analytics-page-views-with-angular-js). Even though I'm not sure if you are using something like Angular or just straight javascript, you could use a similar technique described there with hash urls that are set when a user clicks on a different part of the page, that way you could track how a user interacts with your single page site by making different urls for their interactions.

For more information see [Pushing Functions onto the Queue](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#PushingFunctions).