# AngularDart and Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, dart, angular-dart

How does one go about setting analytics up on an angulardart web application? I read [Tracking Google Analytics Page Views with Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713708/tracking-google-analytics-page-views-with-angular-js) but there isn't a $scope in angulardart. I'm using ng-view, so I'm guessing I need to somehow push a location to the ga variable, most likely in the RouteInitializer implementation? Maybe in the ngRoute section? I'm unsure. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

JS:

```js
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXX', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  });
</script>
```

ROUTER:

```dart
void myRouteInitializer(Router router, RouteViewFactory views) {
  views.configure({
    'home': ngRoute(
        path: '/',
        enter: views('views/home.html')),
    'challenge': ngRoute(
        path: '/challenge/:challengeId',
        enter: views('views/view_challenge.html')),
    'completed': ngRoute(
        path: '/completed',
        enter: views('views/completed.html')),
    '404': ngRoute(
        defaultRoute: true,
        enter: (RouteEnterEvent e) => router.go('home', {}, replace: true))
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your routing is being done with pushState, you should be able to just call

```dart
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This will already [read the correct URL](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages) shown in the address bar, even if it wasn't a real page load. So in theory, this should do everything for you:

```js
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  ga('send', 'pageview');
});
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. I've edited my question to include my router and js. Reading the link in your answer, I found this:

`URL of the page being tracked. By default, analytics.js sets this to the full document URL, excluding the fragment identifier.`

AngularDart uses the fragment. Not sure how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Yeah; that's what I meant by "If your routing is being done with pushState". The fragment is compatible with more browsers, but pushState is the new shiny thing that lets you have /nice/urls and would log with this code.

Comment: Ah I see. Seems as though I had pushState disabled in my main.dart. Enabling does not change my route anymore, which is why I guess I had it disabled to begin with. I'll accept your answer and make a new one as to maybe why it isn't working.

Comment: Returning to add that I went ahead and put `<script type="text/javascript">ga('send', 'pageview', { 'page': window.location.pathname + window.location.hash });</script>` in each of my views that I wanted pushed to google, and can confirm that my views are now being tracked WITHOUT needing pushState enabled. This is for wayward souls looking for an answer

Comment: Is this answer still valid for angularDart 7 in 2022? @Danny Tuppeny