# Google Adwords changes the Landing Page urls for AngularJS pages handled by UI Router

Tags: angularjs, google-ads-api

I have 2 pages designed on AngularJS:

https://www.example.com/book/ [List page]

and

https://www.example.com/book/#/vs [Individual page]

But in Adwords when user clicking on our ads the google tracking id that get's added are like

siteurl/book/?gclid#/vs

where it should have been like siteurl/book/#/vs?gclid .

Even when we are hovering on the Ads displayed in the Google search result page there is no trace of the #/vs part of the url. We see the page url as  siteurl/book/

My question is why it is getting changed in the Adword display in Google search result page from  https://www.example.com/book/#/vs to https://www.example.com/book/ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tracking Google Analytics Page Views with Angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713708/tracking-google-analytics-page-views-with-angular-js)

Comment: @nyuen No it is not a duplicate. See my edited detail