# Insert Google analytics id to script with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I am trying to dynamically insert the google analytics id into the script. Something like this where {{configs[0].ga_id}} stores the id.

```
<script>
google code....

ga('create', '{{configs[0].ga_id}}', 'auto');
</script>
```

this is not working. I have also tried all of these but all are failing.

```
'{configs[0].ga_id}', 
'configs[0].ga_id', 
+ configs[0].ga_id +
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: per MarkoCen

I added this directive and my html looks like this. When inspecting the element the id is displayed properly "UA-XXXXXXXX-1" but in the console.log of of the directive I see this "{{configs[0].ga_id}}"

```
<google-analytics id="{{configs[0].ga_id}}"></google-analytics>

app.directive('googleAnalytics', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: function(elem, attr){
      console.log(attr.id);
      return "<script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create', '" + attr.id + "', 'auto');</script>"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Seems like you should put your GA scripts in an angularJS controller. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713708/tracking-google-analytics-page-views-with-angular-js

Comment: try `console.log(elem[0].id)`

Comment: it came back undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because Google Analytics is not a part of Angular, and the template syntax won't working within a `<script>` tag, you should create a directive to wrap the code:

```
 angular.module('app').directive('googleAnalytics', function(){
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace: true,
       template: function(){
          var configs = [...]; //first get configs from somewhere...
          return "<script>google code... ga('create', '" + configs[0].ga_id + "', 'auto');</script>"
       }
     }
 })
```

then you could insert this directive into `<head>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
   <head>
       <google-analytics></google-analytics>
   </head>
</html>
```